# How to open a new window or switch using a button?

Tags: java, button, canvas, window, awt

I'm trying to figure out this for ages, starting to wonder if it is possible!

I have a starting window for my app - I need it so that when I click on a button I have created, the window either closes and opens a new window or the window resizes and leaves just the canvas (ready to put new widgets, sprites etc... ).

I know I need a handler event for this but I just can't get the code to work.

Comment: *"..just can't get the code to work."*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure whats your question but i coded a example with a JFrame and 3 Buttons.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class OpenWindowAndResizeWindow
{

    private JFrame  frame;
    private JButton btnOpenNewWindow;
    private JButton btnResizeWindow;
    private JButton btnRemoveAllButtons;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    OpenWindowAndResizeWindow window = new OpenWindowAndResizeWindow();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public OpenWindowAndResizeWindow()
    {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(getBtnOpenNewWindow(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(getBtnResizeWindow(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(getBtnRemoveAllButtons(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private void openNewWindow()
    {
        OpenWindowAndResizeWindow newWindow = new OpenWindowAndResizeWindow();
        frame.dispose();

    }
    private void removeButtons()
    {
        getBtnOpenNewWindow().setVisible(false);
        getBtnRemoveAllButtons().setVisible(false);
        getBtnResizeWindow().setVisible(false);
    }
    private void resizeWindow()
    {
        Rectangle rectangle = frame.getBounds();
        rectangle.width = (int)rectangle.getWidth() + 100;
        rectangle.height = (int)rectangle.getHeight() + 100;
        frame.setBounds(rectangle);

    }

    private JButton getBtnOpenNewWindow() {
        if (btnOpenNewWindow == null) {
            btnOpenNewWindow = new JButton("Open new Window");
            btnOpenNewWindow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    openNewWindow();
                }
            });
        }
        return btnOpenNewWindow;
    }
    private JButton getBtnResizeWindow() {
        if (btnResizeWindow == null) {
            btnResizeWindow = new JButton("Resize Window");
            btnResizeWindow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    resizeWindow();
                }
            });
        }
        return btnResizeWindow;
    }
    private JButton getBtnRemoveAllButtons() {
        if (btnRemoveAllButtons == null) {
            btnRemoveAllButtons = new JButton("Remove All Buttons");
            btnRemoveAllButtons.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    removeButtons();
                }
            });
        }
        return btnRemoveAllButtons;
    }
}
```

This code is ready to compile with javac or just paste it in your IDE. 
Maybe this helps a bit. The [Java SE API Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) is useful too.